# Dynamic leiningen :profiles

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to use a function as the value for the `:profiles` key in a `defproject` form. Starting from a fresh project (`lein new app test`) this works fine:

```
:profiles {}
```

(as you might hope!). But if I change it to:

```
:profiles (merge {})
```

then when I run `lein repl` it explodes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Symbol cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry
```

I'm confused by this since if I set `:profiles` back to the empty map and ask the repl these things are equal:

```
test.core=> (= {} (merge {}))
true
```

Where is my misunderstanding? Have I missed something basic? Is this an unfortunate artifact of the `defproject` macro? Something else?

(clojure 1.8.0, leiningen 2.7.1, java 1.8.0_102)

---

### Edit - working solution with Scott's answer:

```
(def project-name 'myproj)
(def mains ["foo" "bar"])
...
(defn- lein-alias [main]
  { main ["with-profile" main] })

(defn- lein-profile [main]
  (let [jar      (str main ".jar")
        entry    `~(str project-name "." main)]
    {(keyword main) {:main          entry 
                     :bin           {:name main}
                     :jar-name      jar
                     :uberjar-name  jar}}))

(defproject project-name "0.1.0"
...
  :profiles ~(apply merge (concat (map lein-profile mains) {:uberjar {:aot :all}}))
  :aliases ~(apply merge (map lein-alias mains))
  ...
```

So now I can `lein foo bin` and `lein bar bin` to my heart's content.

Comment: try unquoting it `~(merge {})`

Comment: @Scott, that works. But why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `unquote` your form Leiningen will execute the form *before* the project map is evaluated.  
 So `~(merge {})` should work.

There is a function called `unquote-project` in Leiningen
[src/leiningen/core/project.clj#L176](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/2.7.1/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/project.clj#L176)

> "Inside defproject forms, unquoting (~) allows for arbitrary evaluation."

It looks like it looks items to `unquote` to allow them to be execute.  Based on the comment it looks like this might go away in **3.0** and suggests `use read-eval syntax`

---

**Note:** If you are just trying to merge values of different profiles you should look at the [Profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/PROFILES.md#merging) documentation About [Merging](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/PROFILES.md#merging) and [Composite Profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/PROFILES.md#composite-profiles)

> **Composite Profiles**
>
> Sometimes it is useful to define a profile as a combination of other profiles. To do this, just use a vector instead of a map as the profile value. This can be used to avoid duplication:

```
{:shared {:port 9229, :protocol "https"}
 :qa [:shared {:servers ["qa.mycorp.com"]}]
 :stage [:shared {:servers ["stage.mycorp.com"]}]
 :production [:shared {:servers ["prod1.mycorp.com", "prod1.mycorp.com"]}]}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was just the bump that I needed. I'll update my question with my solution.

Comment: Beware this bug though https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2132

Answer (score 2):

You do not merge the profiles manually.  They are merged together by `lein` either automatically (normal case) or when you use the `with-profile` keyword (manual control).

For example, consider this `project.clj`:

```
(defproject xyz "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  :dependencies [ [org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"] 
                  [tupelo "0.9.19"] ]

  :profiles {:dev     {:dependencies [ [org.clojure/test.check "0.9.0"]
                                       [criterium "0.4.4"] ] }
             :sample  {:dependencies [medley "0.8.2"] }
  ...
)
```

This `project.clj` says that the project ***always*** requires both `org.clojure/clojure` and `tupelo`.  During development, the map for `:dev` will be merged into the root-level, so `:dependencies` will be updated to include both `test.check` and `criterium`.  The `:dev` profile values are not included when a uberjar is created, however, so these libs won't be included in the code delivered to users.

Since `:sample` is not one of the default profiles, it will only be included if you use a command like:

```
> lein with-profile sample test
```

Notice that the leading colon is not included on the command line, although we use a keyword `:sample` with the colon in the `project.clj` file.

Full details are here:  https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md#default-profiles

and here:  https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj

Having said all this, I normally don't need to use `:profiles`. Unless you have something more complex than usual, you should usually just put all of your dependencies at the root level (i.e. the `:dependencies` keyword at the first level under `(defproject xyz ...)` in the project that `lein new app xyz` gives you.

Another suggestion:  the word `test` is used in many places in a lein project (directory name, file name suffix, and others), so it can be very confusion to name the project itself `test`!  You'll save yourself (and any other readers) some grief if you choose a unique name like `xyz`, `joe`, or anything else.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm fine with the concept of profiles (I think!). My existing project has multiple mains, with multiple profiles to be used with `lein-bin`. Since all of those profiles are very similar I'd like to use a function to generate them (DRY). `(merge {})` was just an example function call that returns a map; `(hash-map)` gives the same result.